# Inject into BroadcastReceiver before onReceive()

Tags: android, dependency-injection, broadcastreceiver, android-testing, dagger-2

I tried to find the answer, how to inject fields into the `BroadcastReceiver`, but everything I find is like this code in the `onReceive()`:

```
((MyApplication) context.getApplicationContext()).getAppComponent().inject(this);
```

I test BroadcastReceiver with

```
MyReceiver receiver = new MyReceiver();
receiver.onReceive(context, testIntent);
```

In this case, it's impossible to inject mocks into the Receiver. How do you manage this situation? I tried to do something like this:

```
@Override public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

  // injecting is here

  onPostInjectReceive(context, intent);
}

void onPostInjectReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

}
```

But even with this workaround it's impossible to make view tests with Espresso, only unit testing. How am I able to inject before I get the callback?

Really I can store BroadcastReceiver component on the App level, but it looks like dirty solution.